# An error occurred (KMS.AccessDeniedException) when calling the SendMessage operation

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-kms

I am getting the below message while run the lambda test run manually.

> errorMessage
>
> An error occurred (KMS.AccessDeniedException) when calling the SendMessage operation: null (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400;
> Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: a8133e94-4948-4dcf-aaf1-7f6b3fd45457; Proxy: null)

actions taken:

1. verify the iam policy and its exist the "sqs:SendMessage" permission in the sqs list.

so, what is missing here to failing this lambda run?

Comment: Is your SQS Queue is encrypted?. Based on the error it seems your Lambda Execution role needs KMS permission (kms:GenerateDataKey, kms:Decrypt/kms:Encrypt)...

Comment: HI Harsha, I have added the KMS permissions and try the test run even though still i am getting the error.

Comment: any luck on that?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm getting the same error for something that works in a different AWS account. I've checked and all the sqs:* and kms:* permissions are assigned correctly.